# How do I load HTML content from divs on one page into multiple divs on another page with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm building a site where I want to use AJAX to replace content in targeted divs on an HTML page with content from divs contained on other HTML pages and navigate by changing links to hashes and appending to the existing url.

I can use the following JQuery code to achieve this and replace a single targeted div using the >load() function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sf-menu a').bind('click', function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#middle .center .inner").load( url + ' #middle .center .inner > *');
        return false;
    });
});
```

but .load() is limited in that it can't target multiple elements and that's what I need to do.

It would be ideal if I could use another method to replace content in a targeted div in the way .load works, but any solution that allows me to replace content in multiple divs with content from another page would be welcome.

It seems I could do something along these lines: (bear with me…new at this…)

```
$.get(URL, function(data) {
    $("#content").html($(data).find('#middle .center .inner '));
    $("#content").html($(data).find('#middle .right .inner '))
});
```

but any examples I can find append the retrieved content somewhere, which still leaves me needing to remove the existing content and I'm not sure how to proceed

Then someone suggested I should be using .ajax for something like this so from some examples I've seen I'm looking at something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'somepage.html',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
    $('#middle .center .inner > *').html($(data).filter('#middle .center .inner').html());
}
```

but I can't get that to function so I must have botched it somewhere.

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong or where I should be focusing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is almost right. Just a little tweak to your code would do the job.

I think you should do the following

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'somepage.html',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
    $('#middle').html($(data).find('#middle').html()); //adding #middle to #middle
    $('.center').html($(data).find('.center').html()); // adding .center to .center
    $('.inner').html($(data).find('.inner').html()); // adding .inner to .inner
}
```

I am assuming there are three different elements namely `#middle`, `.center` and `.inner` on both the pages.

Update
The following line will replace every thing inside `.inner` (which is inside `.center` which is inside `#middle`) with everything that is inside `.inner` (which is inside `.center` which is inside `#middle`) from the requested data.

```
$('#middle .center .inner').html($(data).find('#middle .center .inner').html());
```

If both the elements are same, you can safely call the above line and every thing inside `.inner` will become what ever was in `.inner` from the other page. But if you have to independently set divs inside `.inner` than you will have to give id to every item in `.inner` on both pages.

Comment: Sorry..wasn't clear.. I meant to imply targeting nested divs, i.e., targeted `.inner` is nested inside `.center` is nested inside `#middle` and that there are other .inner divs positioned elsewhere. Would that make my code unncessarily complex? Should I just give any DIVs I want to target unique IDs?

Comment: To anyone trying to get this to work in the context of the original code, you can replace `'somepage.html'` with `url`. The proper URL was set as a variable named url in the preceeding code.